# Is there a way to print all string in capital letters without using strupr function as its not a standard library function?

Tags: c, gcc, file-handling

I want to print the data stored in a file which is randomly cased in all caps and `strupr()` seems to be something that's been listed by someone previously but its not a standard function and may not be cross platform. Is there something which is cross platform?

EDIT 1:

```
                                fgets(input1,254,title);
                                fgets(input2,254,author);
                                input1[strcspn(input1, "\n")] = '\0';
                                input2[strcspn(input2, "\n")] = '\0';
                                printf("<%s> <%s>\n",input1,input2 );
```

I want to print the string stored in `input1` and `input2` in uppercase. How to do that?

Comment: the latter one @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can check if character is in between `a & z` then do `a - 32`. It will be changed to capital letter.

Here `a - 32 = A`, because **ASCII** value of `a` is `97` and `97 - 32 = 65` and we all know that **ASCII** value of `A` is `65`.

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char buffer[255] = {'\0'}, c;
    int i = 0;

    fp = fopen("txt.txt", "r");

    if(!fp)
    {
        perror("txt");
        exit(1);
    }

    while( (c = getc(fp)) != EOF)
        buffer[i++] = c;

    for( i = 0; buffer[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if(buffer[i] >= 'a' && buffer[i] <= 'z')
            buffer[i] = buffer[i] - 32;
        printf("%c", buffer[i]);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
HELLO!
THIS IS 2ND LINE.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can process character by character and use [`toupper()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/toupper). Standard function C89 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom made function, f.e. `upcase()`. It reads every character in the file, checks whether it is lowercase or not (if it is, the character is adjusted to uppercase using the `toupper()` function), stores the whole file content into a buffer and then overwrites the file with the content in the buffer:

```
FILE* upcase (const char* path)
{
    int c, cnt = 0, i = 0, j = 1;
    int n = 500;
    FILE* fp = fopen(path, "r+");

    char* buffer = calloc(n, sizeof(char));

    if (!fp || !buffer)
    {
       return NULL;
    }

    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {  
       if ( i == n )
       {
           j++;
           realloc(buffer, sizeof(char) * (n * j));

           if (!buffer)
           {
               return NULL;
           }

           i = -1;
       }  

       c = toupper(c);
       buffer[i] = c;

       i++;
       cnt++;
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < cnt; i++ )
    {
        if (fputc(c, fp) == EOF)
        {
            fclose(buffer);
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    return fp;    
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, Fails after `2*n`.  Suggest `n = something` in the `if ( i == n )` block.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The idea is that `i` is reset, and `n` is the fixed measurement after how many `char` elements the memory is to be reallocated. I didn't intended to assign a new value to `n`, only `i`.

Comment: OK I now see that now.  I do see a larger issue.  Code does not use the return value of `realloc()`.  The return value is needed  as `realloc(buffer, sizeof(char) * (n * j));` does not change `buffer`.

Comment: Code also never uses `buffer[]` after filling it nor does it free `buffer`.  `fputc(c, fp)` repeatedly tries to print `EOF`.